# Create a workflow that will send email when there is no activity for 30 days

Tags: community

Create a workflow on accounts that will send an email when there is no activity for 30 days?.

the no activity is based on when the user hasn't made a call for 30 days.

Comment: Well before creating a workflow, I think  you should define how do you identify no activity on a account. Business wise, I would identify it as no new opportunities are created under that account or the created opportunities have not moved forward. Looking at it as a developer, I can just check the last modified date. So how do you define activity on an account?

Comment: Based on the LastActivityDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Activity" can be either a Task or an Event. I'm not certain if you're referring to only Tasks or not. Basically, you're talking about Time-Based Workflow. You'd want to create workflow that fires on Task or Event. Assuming you're referring to Task, your workflow should look something like the following:

(First, you don't know if the previous task will have been completed or not. It could easily be overdue by 30 days, so I'll base this on that assumption)

**Evaluation Criteria:**
Evaluate the Rule when a record is created and any time it is subsequenty edited to meet the criteria.

**Rule Criteria:**
Run this rule if the following rule evaluates to true:

```
datevalue(LastModifiedDate) = Today()
```

Save it and add a **Time Trigger**

Workflow Time Trigger Edit

```
30 days after Task:LastModifiedDate
```

Save it and click on the drop-down "Add Workflow Action" to "send an Outbound Message". Create the email template to send the message to the account (or user responsible for the account) related to the task.

If you want the same to apply to Events, you'll need to duplicate the process for Event. Unfortunately without the use of a plug-in like Breeze 3.0, there's no way to evaluate both rules at the same time.